# Joes has replaced visudo

Tags: raspbian, sudo, raspbian-stretch

The title says it all... but now I want the previous Raspbian versions' default behaviour i.e., `visudo` to be the editor for all users when editing the `/etc/sudoers` file.

I'm using Raspbian "Stretch".

Answer (score 1):

> The Debian alternatives system creates a way for several programs that
>   fulfill the same or similar functions to be listed as alternative
>   implementations that are installed simultaneously but with one
>   particular implementation designated as the default. For example many
>   systems have several text editors installed at the same time. The vi
>   program is a classic example of an editor that has many
>   implementations such as nvi, elvis, vim, etc. but which one should be
>   designated as the default?
>
> Debian's alternatives system aims to solve the problem of selecting a
>   default preferred version. Management is done through the
>   update-alternatives program that creates, removes, maintains and
>   displays information about the symbolic links constituting the Debian
>   alternatives system. Priorities are assigned by package creators. The
>   alternative with the highest priority determines the default value
>   when in automatic mode. Additionally the local administrator may
>   override the automatic selection with a manual selection.

https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives